# Spring integration - reliable message delivery with persisted messages

Tags: spring, integration, message

My current setup (partly) is like this:

```
<channel id="chainInboundChannel">
  <queue message-store="mongoDbMessageStore"/>
</channel>

<chain id="myChain" input-channel="chainInboundChannel">
  <service-activator ref="service1" ... />
  <service-activator ref="service2" ... />
  <service-activator ref="service3" ... />
  <service-activator ref="service4" ... />
</chain>
```

Presumably my messages are now persisted. This seems to be true for the time the messages are in the queue. But as a message is received by the chain, it is removed from the message store. So if the application shuts down while the message is being processed by e.g. 'service3', the message is simply lost.

How can I keep the messages persisted while they are being processed inside the chain?

**OPTIONAL:**
What if any of the services returns null at some specific scenario? In this case the message should be removed since it has come to the end of its lifecycle.

Comment: As a workaround, I'm using an extra service-activator as the first in the chain to persist the message, and another service-activator as the last in chain to delete the message.